# jQuery - expand/collapse all button, Internet Explorer problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a custom tree structure type display. I have *Expand all* and *Collapse all* buttons, which are hooked up with the following simple [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

```
        $('#expandAll').click(function() {
            $("img[src='images/plus.gif']").parent().click();
        });
        $('#collapseAll').click(function() {
            $("img[src='images/minus.gif']").parent().click();
        });
```

This works fine in Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer 7 and presumably not in Internet Explorer 6 either. I'm unsure about Internet Explorer 8 since it is not supported where I work.

How can I make it work in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the $ within the selector, like

```
$("img[src$='images/minus.gif']").parent.click();
```

so that it matches the `src` properties ending?

Comment: +1 correct. IE returns the (translated) **absolute URL** for the `src` attribute instead of the actual value.